# Equality comparison of `boolean` and `Object` allowed?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac, autoboxing

The following code

```
public class TestComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean b = true;
        Object o = new Boolean(true);
        System.out.println("comparison result: "+ 
            (o == b)); // Eclipse complains about this expression
    }
}
```

compiles without errors with `javac` V1.7.0_15, and prints "false" when run. However, Eclipse Juno complains about "Incompatible operand types Object and boolean".

Apparently javac autoboxes the primitive boolean `b`, and then compares `o` and autoboxed `b` by object equality, yielding `false`, while Eclipse refuses to do the autoboxing.

Which is the right behaviour according to the Java Language Specification? Where should I file a bug?

*Note:* If I change the type of `o` to `Boolean`, things work as expected: Eclipse accepts the code, and the code prints "true".

[Runnable version on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/7H0028)

Comment: Check your Eclipse Settings and see if there's something funky:

Project Properties -> Java Compiler ->Errors/Warnings -> Potential Programming Problems

Comment: Depends what you "expected" - should it box `b` and use reference equality (printing false) or unbox `o` and use primitive boolean equality (printing true)?

Comment: [java AutoBoxing rules](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/autoboxing.html)

Comment: @IanRoberts: It can't do the latter; the static type of `o` is `Object`.

Comment: In java 6 the code does not compile. It seems there was some changes in specification between java 6 and 7 that allow such behavior, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119638/differences-in-auto-unboxing-between-java-6-vs-java-7. The relavant part is: An expression of a reference type may undergo casting conversion to a primitive type without error, by unboxing conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's your project language level setting. You are probably using a Java 7 compiler with Java 6 semantics. I don't have Eclipse here, but I reproduced it in IntelliJ, which gave errors when the language level was on Java 6, even though the compiler I used was 7. I guess Eclipse has the same. [This link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-with-j2se50.htm) explains it.

Comment: This seems to be the problem. I can reproduce the problem with `javac -source 1.6`, so it seems the problem is caused by the change from 1.6 to 1.7. However, Eclipse shows the error even for "Compiler compliance level = 1.7". This might be a bug in the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: @sleske I confirm all that :/

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your 'Note' that the code compiles and works when `o` is changed to `Boolean`:

This code:

```
public class Tester{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Boolean one = new Boolean(true);
    Object two = new Boolean(true);
    boolean three = true;
    System.out.println("SAME 1:2 " + (one == two) + " 1:3 " + (one == three) + " 2:3 " + (two == three));
    System.out.println("EQUAL 1:2 " + (one.equals(two)) + " 1:3 " + (one.equals(three)) + " 2:3 " + (two.equals(three)));
  }
}
```

produces this result:

```
SAME 1:2 false 1:3 true 2:3 false
EQUAL 1:2 true 1:3 true 2:3 true
```

To see why this is, we need to consider the *compile-time* types of the various expressions:

- `one == two` compares a `Boolean` with an `Object` - these are both reference types, so the test is reference equality ([Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 edition, §15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3))
- `one == three` compares a `Boolean` with a `boolean` - this is treated as a comparison of primitive `boolean` values ([§15.21.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2)); `one` is unboxed and compared with `three`.
- `two == three` compares an `Object` with a `boolean` - in this case the `boolean` is converted to `Object` by a casting conversion ([§5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5), in this case boxing `boolean` to `Boolean` and then widening `Boolean` to `Object`) and the two are then compared for reference equality.

The `EQUAL` line is much simpler - all three cases are calls to `Boolean.equals(Object other)`, using boxing when the argument is `three`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So for `two==three`, both a cast and boxing/unboxing are necessary, and Java will first autobox, and then cast.