# When is it legal to compare Objects and primitives with '==' operator?

Tags: java, operators, autoboxing, jls

Is the below (Java) code legal?

```
class Test {
  Object foo() {return "";}
  boolean bar() {return foo() == true;}
}
```

It won't compile against JDK 6 but seems fine on 7+. Did the spec change? Was a bug fixed? I've been discussing at http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416950 and could go either way on this one.

Comment: check this previous post , [difference in autoboxing java6 and java7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119638/differences-in-auto-unboxing-between-java-6-vs-java-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it is *not* legal to compare a primitive with an expression of compile-time type 'Object'. [JLS 15.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) expressly forbids it:

> The equality operators may be used to compare two operands that are
> convertible ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to numeric type, or two operands of type boolean
> or Boolean, or two operands that are each of either reference type or
> the null type. All other cases result in a compile-time error.

The Eclipse compiler flags the error regardless of Java version. For Java 7, both Oracle JDK and OpenJDK erroneously allow the code to compile. This [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8013357) in Oracle and Open JDKs is corrected in version 8.

In summary, this wonky comparison is illegal according to the spec and will only compile on some subset of compilers for a particular subset of language version targets. Won't ever work on Java 4- or 8+. The casting conversions referred to in other answers apply only to the '=' operator, not to '=='. [15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) applies only to two reference operands.

Answer (score 3):

JLS about reference equality doesn't change between java 6 & 7:

[Chapter 15.21.3: Reference Equality Operators == and !=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) :

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference
>   type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.
>
> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of
>   either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion
>   (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be
>   unequal.

However I noticed some change on [Chapter 5.5: Casting Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5). Casting boolean to Object appears to be classified as boxing convention on Java 7:

> An expression of a primitive type may undergo casting conversion to a
>   reference type without error, by boxing conversion.

[image]

⊡ signifies boxing conversion

Hence since the primitive `true` can be casted to `Object`, your equality expression can be classified as reference equality on Java 7, and doesn't yield compiler error

Answer (score 0):

Here's the byte code for reference

```
class Test {
  Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
       4: return

  java.lang.Object foo();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String
       2: areturn

  boolean bar();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #3                  // Method foo:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       4: iconst_1
       5: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:
       8: if_acmpne     15
      11: iconst_1
      12: goto          16
      15: iconst_0
      16: ireturn
}
```

Compiled with

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

It seems to be converting the returned `String` into a `Boolean` that gets unboxed.