# Cannot cast from Object to char

Tags: java, casting

My code works perfectly as far as I can see but I still get the error "Cannot cast from Object to char" and I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what the problem is and if I can do it another way that does not cause an error.

This is the bit of code causing the error `char op = (char) term;`. It is from an infix to postfix converter

```
//Take terms off the queue in proper order and evaluate
private double evaluatePostfix(DSAQueue<Object> postfixQueue) {
    DSAStack<Double> operands = new DSAStack<Double>();
    Object term; 

    //While still terms on queue, take term off.
    while(!postfixQueue.isEmpty()) {
        term = postfixQueue.dequeue();
        if(term instanceof Double) { //If term is double put on stack
            operands.push((Double) term);
        }
        else if(term instanceof Character) { //If term is character, solve
            double op1 = operands.pop();
            double op2 = operands.pop();
            char op = (char) term;
            operands.push(executeOperation(op, op2, op1));
        }
    }
    return operands.pop(); //Return evaluated postfix
}
```

Any help (even pointing me to some reading) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tried casting to `Character` instead?

Comment: [Java Tutorial: Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html), at the very least read about primitive data types and objects.

Comment: No, no I had not. I feel incredibly stupid now haha but thank you @EvanKnowles

Comment: You probably run it on JDK 6, since JDK7 this is allowed. You can read more about this in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119638/differences-in-auto-unboxing-between-java-6-vs-java-7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
char op = (Character) term;
```

Explanation: *in Java 6* you can't cast an `Object` to a primitive type, but you *can* cast it to `Character` (which is a class) and unboxing does the rest :)

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you can bump the language level of your project up to *Java 7* (or 8...)

Comment: As I know, you can cast objects to primitive datatypes in jdk1.6

Comment: Actually it got changed in JDK1.7 JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5, Java 7 allows unboxing of Object to primitive

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Since term is an instance of Character you could even assign it directly without casting as char op = term if you are using jdk 1.5+

One possibility i could see is the compiler compliance level used. You might have a JDK 1.5+ but you are compiling your project in a lower level. If you are using eclipse check for JDK compliance level in Project->properties->Java Compiler

If you are directly compiling or using Ant build check for -source & -target options.

And just for your info, as far as i know Object to primitive casting was introduced in JDK 1.7. So if you are using JDk 1.7+ you could wirte as

```
Object term = 'C';
char op = (char) term;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java can't auto unbox and cast in one operation, which is what you're trying to do. Instead, cast it to `Character` and java will auto unbox it OK:

```
char op = (Character) term;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't *cast* from an *object* to a *primitive* data type (or vice versa). They are two very different things.

Java `lang` package has classes that correspond to each primitive: `Float` for `float`, `Boolean` for `boolean`..

As others already stated, you should cast the *object* to `Character` and not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to chang

```
char op = (Character) term;
```

because you have to cast with class refference not using the primitive type.