# Ternary expression could produce null-boolean without compiler error?

Tags: java, java-8

Given the following code:

```
boolean c = true;
boolean d = true;
boolean b = c ? null : d;

System.out.println(b);
```

Why does the compiler not complain here?
Variable b is a primitive datatype, shouldn't the null produce an error message like "Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to boolean"?

My best guess is, that there's some autoboxing going on? 
I saw this code in a project, but I would love to know the exact reason behind this...

EDIT1:
As noted below by Mena, this code produces a NullPointer during runtime

EDIT 2:
the following form also compiles without error:

```
boolean c = false;
boolean d = true;
boolean b = c ? null : d;

System.out.println(b);
```

EDIT 3:
When trying to compile with compiler level 1.4, this will NOT compile, but produce an error:

```
Incompatible conditional operand types null and boolean.
```

So auto-boxing would make sense, as it was introduced with 1.5?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119638/differences-in-auto-unboxing-between-java-6-vs-java-7

Comment: Worth noting that while this does compile, it will throw `NullPointerException` at runtime.

Comment: @HadiJ That is not relevant to this question (local variables don't have a default value, nor is a default value relevant when explicitly assigning)

Comment: Your last edit can be pretty easily explained: Java 1.4 didn't have boxing of primitives.

Answer (score 1):

The expression on the RHS is of type `Boolean` and will be auto-unboxed at runtime; compile time type checking won't be affected. The unboxing will lead to a runtime exception.

Comment: that was my thought too. could you provide a source for your answer? would like to better understand why this is happening

Comment: @zeisi https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.1

Comment: It's generally always legal to assign an expression of a boxed type to a primitive variable (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for example. The compiler cannot do a null check of arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This does not compile, since we can not assign the null value to a variable of primitive type

```
boolean e = null;
```

This also does not compile, although there is a decision, the compiler detects that the value is always null and the same as the previous case

```
boolean f = c ? null : null;
```

In this case, as the compiler does not know the final value of b then the code compiles, but fails to run because finally the value is null

```
boolean c = true;
boolean d = true;
boolean b = c ? null : d;
```

Answer (score -1):

The types in the ternary expressions have to be *of the same type*, so I guess the `JLS`  says that the types are auto-boxed in such a case (it will become `Boolean`); considering how little checks/optimizations `javac` does, this is not done here. It's interesting that intellij does complain for example, that a *potential* `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

To me, this somehow falls in the same category of:

```
String s = null;

if (true == true) {

}

if(s == null) {

}
```

and the like... they all are known at compile time for us, but not for the compiler.

A little bit un-related, but a ternary operator is far from an `if statement`, Holger once showed me this awesome example with promotion:

```
boolean b = true;
Object result = b ? Integer.valueOf(42) : Long.valueOf(12);
System.out.println(result.getClass() + "  " + result); // class java.lang.Long  42
```